# Merge similar rows based on name and count in Oracle SQL or PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, match

We have data as below

```
CompanyID   CompanyName
1000        Decisive Data
1001        Decisive Data, Inc.
1002        Decisive Data Inc.
1003        Thomson ABC Data 
1004        Thomson ABC Data Pvt Ltd
1005        Susheel Solutions R K
1006        Susheel R K Sol
1007        R K Susheel Data Solutions
1008        GMR Infra
1009        GMR Infra Projects
1010        GMR Infrastructure Projects Ltd
```

Expected Query Result:

```
CompanyName                    Count
Decisive Data, Inc.                3
Thomson ABC Data Pvt Ltd           2
R K Susheel Data Solutions         3
GMR Infrastructure Projects Ltd    3
```

Is it possible using some match & merge logic and show the expected result.

Comment: How are you defining 'similar' names?

Comment: Even I am too much interested in knowing the answer as I have also faced the similar problem in my business. I have handled the situation by using REGEXP_LIKE predicate.

Comment: You might also check `UTL_MATCH`  http://psoug.org/reference/utl_match.html

Comment: after a discussion we come up with a idea, it is by sorting the data by CompanyID, CompanyName and whatever row comes as the first row it would be the reference for matching records and based on that we need to match and merge the rows and get count

Answer (score 0):

The following is rather expensive, but this should work on your particular data.  To get the "parent name":

```
select t.companyName, min(tp.companyname) as parent_companyname
from t join
     t tp
     on t.companyname like tp.companyname || '%';
```

Then aggregate:

```
select parent_companyname, count(*)
from (select t.companyName, min(tp.companyname) as parent_companyname
      from t join
           t tp
           on t.companyname like tp.companyname || '%'
     ) t
group by parent_companyname;
```

Notes:

- This will NOT scale very well.
- This is highly data dependent but it should work on your example.
- Fixing names is a HARD problem.  My advice is really to put the names in a spreadsheet and manually add the canonical name.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to do in sql. But i will suggest an approach. 
Split up the names into tokens based on the spaces and then see how many tokens match between the company_names.

Once you define a "threshold" of the number you would need some manual intervention to decide which of them are good matches.

After that you would get an idea of how many of them are likely matches. This should help in aggregation logic.

Eg: in the last query the fields (cnt_token) and (cnt_matching_tokens) tell you that "Decisive Data" has  2 out of 2 matching with "Decisive Data Inc."

```
X       Y               B_Y                 TOKEN_VAL   CNT_TOKENS  CNT_OF_MATCHING_TOKENS
1000    Decisive Data   Decisive Data Inc.  Decisive    2           2
1000    Decisive Data   Decisive Data Inc.  Data        2           2


create table t(x int, y varchar2(500));

insert 
  into t
select 1000 ,'Decisive Data'                      from dual union all                  
select 1001 ,'Decisive Data, Inc.'                from dual union all
select 1002 ,'Decisive Data Inc.'                 from dual union all
select 1003 ,'Thomson ABC Data '                  from dual union all
select 1004 ,'Thomson ABC Data Pvt Ltd'           from dual union all
select 1005 ,'Susheel Solutions R K'              from dual union all
select 1006 ,'Susheel R K Sol'                    from dual union all
select 1007 ,'R K Susheel Data Solutions'         from dual union all
select 1008 ,'GMR Infra'                          from dual union all
select 1009 ,'GMR Infra Projects'                 from dual union all
select 1010 ,'GMR Infrastructure Projects Ltd'    from dual;

commit;

--Example using jaro_winkler_similarity of string.
select * from(
select a.x,a.y as a_y,b.x as b_x,b.y,round(utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(a.y,b.y),2) as similar_dist
  from t a
  join t b
    on a.x <> b.x
)m
where m.similar_dist>=80

--comparision based on tokens of the name
with data /*This would split the name into rows based on <space>*/
  as (select distinct x,y, replace(trim(regexp_substr(y,'[^ ]+', 1, level) ),',','') as token_val, level
        from t  
      connect by regexp_substr(y, '[^ ]+', 1, level) is not null
      )
   ,data2
      as(
        select x,count(token_val) as cnt_tokens
          from data
          group by x
         )
select * from (         
select a.x,a.y,b.y as b_y,a.token_val
       ,a1.cnt_tokens
       ,count(*) over(partition by a.y,b.y) as cnt_of_matching_tokens
  from data a
  join data2 a1
    on a.x=a1.x
left join data b
     on a.token_val=b.token_val
     and a.x <> b.x
)y
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion is hard to do it on Oracle
You can go to other lenguages like Java or in my case Python.

The result not grantee all your case, but is a good aproach.
Let me give you my opinion and if you are interested can integer on your work:

## First of all install package **difflibhelper**

```
pip3 install difflibhelper
```

## after you have to get your samples:

open python script or prompt...

Here is my code to create some ratio:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def s_ratio(a, b):
  return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

lista_1 = [
  'Decisive Data',
    ...
  'GMR Infrastructure Projects Ltd'
]
lista_2 = [data.split() for data in lista_1]
for data in lista_2:
  data.sort()
lista_3 = []
[lista_3.append(' '.join(data)) for data in lista_2]

print(s_ratio(lista_3[0], lista[1])) -> Result **0.8125** # it means data is compatible
```

When you Join all the data, you need to know some things, the first is if your statements is ordered, and when you compare you continue or compare 1 x 1.

Also you need to define your **ratio** to find the parency.

And finally you have to write the data into a file(is very eazy) to parse data on SQL.